# Is "do something against sth" acceptable when meaning "do something about sth"?

Tags: collocations

As a native German speaker, I was taught that the correct translation of "etwas gegen etwas tun", which would literally translate as "to do something against something", was "to do something ABOUT something", e.g. "You have to do something about this noise!". Since I keep reading "to do something against something", I'm now wondering if "do something against something" does not work at all, or if it would just be less common?

Comment: I would say "does not work at all".

Answer (score 2):

You're right, "against" (the literal translation of German *gegen*) [can have  this meaning in English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/against):

> **against** *preposition* (AS PROTECTION)
>
> as a protection or defence from the bad effects of:
>
> - *We've insured the car against fire, theft, and accident.*
> - *The police have to arm themselves against attack.*

But this meaning is not idiomatic with all verbs or in all situations. The usage of *gegen* in German is more broad than *against* in English. You can *fight against (some bad thing)*, you can *protect against* something, but in all these cases there's a clear sense of opposition, confrontation, defense, protection, etc. which comes both from the verb and from the preposition.

"Do" is a very generic verb, as in German (*tun*), and it doesn't really work with *against*. "*Do something against the noise*" is grammatical, but sounds very unnatural and is not at all idiomatic. "*Do something about the noise*" is indeed a much better translation.

Comment: Wir fahren gegen Engeland...